# Why does my function keep looping without a loop in Python?

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop

The following code loops after line 30. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? After typing [done] in the message, it just shows the 'title>>' prompt again.

```
from lxml import etree
import time
import datetime

def memory():
    ts = time.time()
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    post = open('post.txt', 'w')
    document = etree.Element('document')
    title = raw_input('title>>')

    while 1:
        message = raw_input('post>>')
        post.write(message + '\n')
        if '[done]' in message:
            post.close()
            break

    post = open('post.txt', 'r')
    postf = post.read()

    article = etree.SubElement(document, 'article', title=title, date=st)
    article.text = postf

    post.close()

    with open('postf.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(etree.tostring(document, pretty_print=True) + '\n')
        file.close()

    return(document, article)




memory()

document = memory()
article = memory()

print etree.tostring(document, pretty_print=True)
print '<<Your Message>>'
print article.text
```

It should loop the 'post>>' prompt until [done] is seen, and then it should break the loop and just finish out the function. I have a feeling it's something simple, but I've been changing things for the last hour and a half to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you realize that you are calling `memory()` three times, so you should expect to see `title` at least 3 times?

Comment: ...Duh. I forgot that the parenthesis called it... I am dumb. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. I did not write it as an answer because I wasn't sure whether it was oversight or you actually had `title` showing up repeatedly after 3 times.